# Add confguration for type casting in pyodbc driver

Tags: python, pandas, pip, pyodbc, read-sql

I am trying to read a stored procedure by using `pandas.read_sql` method in Python by using the pyodbc driver.
The issue I have is when Pandas reads data, it converts `int` columns to `float` which have Null values in it.

Is there a way to fill those null values at pyodbc driver by applying some configuration or hooking some custom converters?

I do not want to change that on SQL level or when i read it through pandas.

Comment: Also being discussed on GitHub [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/961).

Answer (score 0):

It's because that **int** column contains some **Null** values and dataframe is converting it to float64. You can typecast your column to **"Int64"**

eg: `df['id'] = df['id'].astype("Int64")`